# reveal content hidden/nested in two accordions using fragment URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I try to find a solution for the following problem on my page:

- I have many accordions on my page
- Some accordions (lets call them _main) reveal on click other accordions (lets call those _sub) and the _sub reveal on click content like tables with data
- Each accordion got his own fragment URL (like #sub_1_A or #test1_main)
- if one access the page using fragment URL #accordion_main the accordion open and show its content
- but if one access the page using a fragment URL for a sub like #sub_1_A the belonging _main doesn't open. Even though the _sub open and reveal its content but the user can't see it because the _main is still closed

I tried to write a small jQuery script which should perform a click on _main before the click on _sub has happened. But that doesnt work the _main is still closed.

**So the question is, how can I also open the _main accordion when a user access the page using a _sub accordion fragtment URL?**

 
Here are some code snippets:

```
<!-- Accordion Element 2 Sub -->
<div class="balken"><div class="balkenclosed"><a id="test1_main" 
style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="#test_1_main">
Test 1 main element</a></div></div>

<div class="inhalt">
<!-- some code which create tabs -->

<!-- Accordion Element 2 Sub -->
<div class="balken"><div class="balkenclosed"><a id="sub1A"
style="text-decoration:none; color:black;" href="#sub_1_A">
Sub 1 A element</a></div></div>

<div class="inhalt">
<!-- some code which create content/tables -->
```

With this script I tried to make a click on the div which contain the _main accordion

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('#') !== -1) {
$('test1_main').trigger('click');
$('#' + window.location.href.split('#')[1]).parent().click(); }
```

I also made a [codepen](https://codepen.io/undefined999/pen/vprBGp) with those snippets.

 
Here are some links to my test page to clarify my problem:

 
[link to a main accordion - open](http://undefined.bplaced.net/produkte/hauptprodukt_2/current/index.html#Hersteller_A)

 
[link to a sub accordion - not open](http://undefined.bplaced.net/produkte/hauptprodukt_2/current/index.html#Typenuebersicht_2_A)

Comment: You would need to check the hash onload and if it is one of the child tabs, then open the parent programatically using the active option when you instantiate it - more info in the manual: http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: Thanks for your comment, Pete But how does the tab stuff would help with the accodions? Or do you mean I can use code/widgets/options from the tabs on the accordions too?

Comment: Sorry, yeah, got sidetracked answering too many questions at the same time, there is also an active option on the accordions - http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/

Comment: Thanks Pete, this problem is really going to cause headache

Comment: @Pete I checked this stuff out during the weekend. But I feel like I would have to rewrite all my code and basically start from scratch to use that jquery UI. Do you maybe have an other idea how I could solve that issue without rewriting everything?